Confusion Matrix in SQL
I have some rules which gets fired if a criteria for a process gets fulfilled. I am calculating the performance of those rules in a confusion matrix form.
If the rule was fired, it means the process was predicted positive. So if the process was actually positive that'll be a True Positive scenario 
If the rule was fired, it means the process was predicted positive. So if the process was not actually positive that'll be a False Positive scenario 
If the rule_name is NULL, it means none of the rule was fired, So if the process was actually negative that's a False Negative scenario.
Note: if a process is null in the rule_name, that's a false negative for every rule because none of the rule got fired while the process actually failed.



id
rule_name
true_label
predicted_label




1
rule1
positive
positive


2
rule1
positive
positive


3
rule1
negative
positive


4
null
positive
positive


5
null
positive
positive


6
null
negative
positive


7
rule2
positive
positive


8
rule2
negative
positive


9
rule2
negative
positive



My result set should look like:




True Positive
False Positive
True Negative
False Negative




rule1
1
1
1
2


rule2
1
2
1
2



I am doing this in SQL. I can do this by filtering each rule_name i.e.

select 'rule1' as rule
    , count(case when rule_name = 'rule1' and true_label = 'positive' and predicted_label = 'positive' then 1 else null  end)as tp_count
    , count(case when rule_name = 'rule1' and true_label != 'positive' and predicted_label = 'positive' then 1 else null  end)as fp_count
    , count(case when (rule_name != 'rule1' or rule_name is null) and and true_label != 'positive' then 1 else null end) as tn_count
from table
;

I have multiple such rules so, I don't want to do this calculation each rule with union all I am looking for a better way to do this calculation. My main challenge is to count the True Negatives where I need to count the rule_name NULLs as well.

It looks like you simply want to group by the rule name, so as to get one result row per rule:
select 
  rule_name,
  count(*) filter (where true_label = 'positive' and predicted_label = 'positive') as tp_count,
  count(*) filter (where true_label = 'negative' and predicted_label = 'positive') as fp_count,
  count(*) filter (where true_label = 'negative' and predicted_label = 'negative') as tn_count,
  count(*) filter (where true_label = 'positive' and predicted_label = 'negative') as fn_count
from table
group by rule_name
order by rule_name;


How does COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE <expr>) compare to COUNT( CASE WHEN <expr> END ) ?

@Dai: This is the standard SQL syntax for conditional aggregation. It is just a tad more readable and a little less prone to mistakes. That's it. No big deal. It should be the prefered syntax. PostgreSQL supports it, so I am using it.

I like this (optional SQL standard) FILTER syntax. Too bad it isn't widely implemented, so code using it instead of a case expression isn't very portable.

To solve this problem in a more dynamic and efficient way in SQL (specifically PostgreSQL), you can use a combination of GROUP BY, CASE, and window functions. Here’s a solution that avoids manually filtering each rule and dynamically handles all rules in a single query.
SQL Query:
WITH rule_performance AS (
    SELECT
        COALESCE(rule_name, 'no_rule') AS rule_name,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN true_label = 'positive' AND predicted_label = 'positive' THEN 1 END) AS tp_count,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN true_label != 'positive' AND predicted_label = 'positive' THEN 1 END) AS fp_count,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN (rule_name != r.rule_name OR rule_name IS NULL) AND true_label != 'positive' THEN 1 END) AS tn_count,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN rule_name IS NULL AND true_label = 'positive' THEN 1 END) AS fn_count
    FROM
        your_table t
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT rule_name FROM your_table WHERE rule_name IS NOT NULL) r 
    ON 
        t.rule_name = r.rule_name OR t.rule_name IS NULL
    GROUP BY
        COALESCE(rule_name, 'no_rule')
)
SELECT
    rule_name,
    tp_count,
    fp_count,
    tn_count,
    fn_count
FROM
    rule_performance
ORDER BY
    rule_name;

Now try this code.

You can simplify this SQL further by using the IS DISTINCT FROM operator, btw.
